# Automapper mapping of complex objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I am using Automapper to map my Model objects to DTO. In DTO the primary key should be replaced with the corresponding object. For this purpose I used the code below:

```
// Model class
public class SubDepartment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}

// DTO class
public class SubDepartmentDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public long EventCount { get; set; }
}

// Mapping code

 Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Event.SubDepartment, DTO.SubDepartment>().ForMember(dto => dto.Department,
                map => map.MapFrom(sd => Mapper.Map<Department, DTO.Department>(_departmentRepository.GetById(sd.DepartmentId.Value))));
```

But when I map from SubDepartment to SubDepartmentDTO in my controller, the 'Department' object is always null. I tried replacing the `_departmentRepository.GetById(sd.DepartmentId.Value)` code with a hardcoded Department object and it is working good. I also verified there is a corresponding Department exist in the database for the primary key. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It feels like you are doing too much in your mapper. It should be mapping between objects, not executing database calls. Have you tried loading the data into an object and then mapping that object to the dto.department? Basically you'd be calling map twice, once for the parent and once for the child object.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this code

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Event.SubDepartment, DTO.SubDepartment>().ForMember(dto => dto.Department,map => map.MapFrom(sd => _departmentRepository.GetById(sd.DepartmentId.Value)));
```

if it doesn't work you could try Custom value resolver

```
Models.Event.SubDepartment, DTO.SubDepartment>().ForMember(dto => dto.Department, map => map.ResolveUsing<DepartmentResolver>());

public class DepartmentResolver: ValueResolver<Models.Event.SubDepartment,DTO.SubDepartment>
{
    Reporsitory _departmentRepository;
    protected override DTO.SubDepartment ResolveCore(Models.Event.SubDepartment source)
    {
        return _departmentRepository.GetById(source.DepartmentId.Value);
    }
}
```